# Palavra chave As e Is no C#

Tags: c#, .net, orientação-a-objetos

Bom... fiquei meio confuso quanto as palavras chave As e Is no C#... não entendi a diferença entre elas nem pra que servem... acredito que não seja tão difícil achar uma esplicação na internet, mas prefiro perguntar aqui, porque os sites não aprofundaram muito nesse assunto...

Comment: Conforme eu já orientei antes seria interessante pesquisar antes de perguntar. Quase tudo o que quer saber já foi respondido por usuários experientes no site e já tiveram as respostas classificadas como boas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"is" e "as" são palavras chaves usadas para converter tipos de dados.
"is": verifica se um se um objeto é compatível com um tipo de dados e retorna true ou false.
Ex: if(obj is Produto) {}.
"as" tenta fazer a conversão de um objeto em um tipo específico. Se a conversão falhar ele retorna nulo.

Para ajudar a entender melhor a diferença nesse link tem um boa explicação com exemplos de códigos.
http://www.macoratti.net/17/11/c_isas1.htm